# Close tkinter GUI without killing the app

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using Tkinter to create a GUI program on python 2.7.

At some point, I want to open an informative window and close it automatically later on, the problem is, when I call quit on it the whole application closes.

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("WINDOW")


def create_wnd(xxx, yyy):
    yyy.destroy()

def run_wnd():
    dialog = tk.Toplevel()
    dialog.title("wnd2")


wnd_run_button = tk.Button(root, text="RUN", command=lambda:run_wnd())
wnd_run_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Put "the rest of the application" after the call to `mainloop`. Killing the window causes `mainloop` to exit, but any code after that will continue to run.

Or, put all of the window code inside a function that finishes by calling `mainloop, so the function won't exit until the window is destroyed. The code that calls the function will continue as soon as the function returns.